# offline_message_hook is not called

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

i am working on offline notification.
i have tried this code http://jasonrowe.com/2011/12/30/ejabberd-offline-messages/

i am using `mod_http_offline` module.
when user send offline message i got below error in my error log

```
running hook: {offline_message_hook,[{jid,<<"1112121212">>,   
              <<"xyz.com.com">>,<<"26112267011450933160669531">>,
              <<"11121212">>,<<"xyz.com">>,
              <<"26112267011450933160669531">>},{jid,<<"12121212">>,
              <<"xyz.com">>,<<"10640377501450932768366216">>,
              <<"918787878787">>,<<"xyz.com">>, 
              <<"10640377501450932768366216">>},{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"121212121@xyz.com">>},{<<"to">>,<<"11111111@xyz.com/10640377501450932768366216">>},
             {<<"id">>,<<"AqLgKTeu">>}],[{xmlel,<<"x">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:x:event">>}],[{xmlel,<<"delivevered">>,[],[]},{xmlel,<<"id">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"EYx1Bhh0">>}]}]}]}]}


[error] <0.3631.0>@ejabberd_hooks:run1:332 {function_clause,[{lists,thing_to_list,[<<>>],[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,601}]}
        {lists,flatmap,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},{lists,flatmap,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},{mod_http_offline,post_offline_message,3,[{file,"mod_http_offline.erl"},
        {line,38}]},{ejabberd_hooks,safe_apply,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,382}]},
        {ejabberd_hooks,run1,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,329}]},
        {ejabberd_sm,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_sm.erl"},{line,111}]},
        {ejabberd_local,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_local.erl"},{line,112}]}]}

[error] <0.3703.0>@ejabberd_config:validate_opts:794 unknown option 'loopback' will be likely ignored
[error] <0.3703.0>@ejabberd_config:validate_opts:794 unknown option 'local' will be likely ignored
```

Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Comment: This module is probably too old to work on latest ejabberd. It need to be updated.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond , currently we are using [https://github.com/raelmax/mod_http_offline/blob/master/README.md ] module.
my erlang version  version: 17.1 and erlang emulator version 6.3
please let me know latest mod_http_offline module or give url from where we can download latest version of http_offline_module  which is compatible with ejabberd 15.11

Comment: You should ask the author to update the code or patch it to make it work on latest version I guess.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond , is there any other option or link available?? its take lot of time to get response from author for updated code. hope you have another way or option.

Answer (score 0):

You are running a module calling `lists:thing_to_list/1`. This function does not handle binary. That's the reason why your code is crashing (`function clause`).

Somewhere in your code you are trying to concat a list with an empty binary (`<<>>`), which is not possible.

Here is an example triggering the error:

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V7.2  (abort with ^G)
1> lists:concat(["Hello", <<>>]).
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    lists:thing_to_list(<<>>) (lists.erl, line 602)
     in function  lists:flatmap/2 (lists.erl, line 1249)
     in call from lists:flatmap/2 (lists.erl, line 1249)
```